# Project Hamster indicator: mono icons

Tags: indicator, icons

Does anybody know where to find the mono icons described [here](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2011/06/ubuntu-mono-icons-for-hamster-time-tracker-indicator-applet/)?
The download links are broken.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find them on the project's github page (which is linked from the article). More specifically you can find them at https://github.com/tseliot/hamster-appindicator/tree/master/data/icons . Note that they're available for different themes and both in raster graphics (.png) and in vector graphics (.svg).